# Flex - How to browse and get the full path of a file on local machine's file system?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am working with Flex, Flash, Action Script and I want to browse the local machine file system using Operating System's file browse window and select a file then i want to get the full path of the selected file. How can I do this? Please give me some code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flash Player 10, you can use a [`FileReference`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html) to get the name or load the data of a file on the local filesystem, but are *purposely restricted* from getting the full file path and many other operations available with AIR's [`File`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [`FileStream`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

I think its the nativePath (which gives it in the OS's representation) property on the File object.

Here is a link: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Filesystem_03.html

Comment: i am not developing on AIR, this is for AIR developing as I can see!!!
what is the solution for flash?

Comment: If you aren't using AIR then you can't do what you want.

Comment: are they restrict the file system access, browse file system etc in flash?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can access the local files of the operating system in AIR applications.Plz correct me if wrong