# IPython Notebook Open File Dialog (retrieve the full path)

Tags: javascript, python, html, jupyter-notebook, file-browser

An ipython notebook is a document that is read by the browser that contains both rich text and python code.

In scientific computing ipython notebooks are often used to perform an analysis some input data file that resides on the local file system.

Instead of manually pasting the full path of the file containing the data into a variable, would be convenient to be able to launch an open-file dialog in order to browse the local file system and select the file. The full path of the file should be returned in a variable (in python).

This can be achieved launching an open-file dialog from a GUI toolkit (i.e. QT). For an example see [IPython Notebook: Open/select file with GUI (Qt Dialog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790926/ipython-notebook-open-select-file-with-gui-qt-dialog).

However, using QT has some disadvantages. First it is an additional dependency. Second it requires enabling the QT gui integration in the notebook and this results in conflicts with the inline plots (see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5798)).

The question here is, is it possible to obtain the full path using only Javascript?

**EDIT:** The answer posted below only returns the file name, not the full-path.

Comment: Re-edited to make the question more clear.

Comment: IPython notebook has autocompletion for paths: begin typing a path (say "/home/") and press tab: it lists all the files in /home/.

Answer (score 13):

Using the HTML5 construct `<input type="file">` is possible to instruct the browser to open a file selector dialog. Then we need to bind a javascript function to the "changed event".

The javascript can use `kernel.execute(command)` to execute a command on the python kernel that assign a variable with the selected file path.

Here an example:

```
input_form = """
<div style="border:solid navy; padding:20px;">
<input type="file" id="file_selector" name="files[]"/>
<output id="list"></output>
</div>
"""

javascript = """
<script type="text/Javascript">
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    console.log('Executing orig')
    console.log(files)
    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    var f = files[0]
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</_Mli>');
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    var command = 'fname = "' + f.name + '"'
    console.log(command)
    kernel.execute(command);
  }

  document.getElementById('file_selector').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
"""

def file_selector():
    from IPython.display import HTML, display
    display(HTML(input_form + javascript))
```

After the previous definitions putting in a cell `file_selector()` will display a button "Choose file" and after a file is selected the variable `fname` in the notebook will contain the file path.

### References

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/

Comment: i tried that but fname only has the fileName not the path

Comment: fname is not found in my case, although the selector does show up

Comment: Only the filename is displayed, not the fullpath, and this is explained in the answer by @2diabolos.com

Comment: The code above no longer works in Jupyter Lab v3.1.14. and Jupyter Classic NB launced from the Help menu in JupyterLab.  It only displays "Browse..." No file selected.  More complete instructions are needed for how to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

this other StackOverflow 
"[How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)"
has already cleared the question : you can't get local fullpath from HTML (5 or previous) interface due to security politic. 
So it is normal that you need QT (or equivalent) to get what you need.

I've been searching a Flash equivalent, but it seems that you may only have it with AIR according to this StackOverflow :
"[Flex - How to browse and get the full path of a file on local machine's file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539464/flex-how-to-browse-and-get-the-full-path-of-a-file-on-local-machines-file-sys)"